# Draw vertical line with google charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization

I have the following table, with which I created a chart with Google Charts (https://www.google.com/jsapi), all in PHP and JavaScript:

The table:

[image]

The graphic:

[image]

The code for the graphic is the following:

```
<?php $result_chart =  sqlsrv_query($con1, $sSQL ); /*Get the data from database*/

$rows = array();

$table = array();

$table ['cols'] = array(

  array ('label' => 'L [µH]', 'type' => 'number'),

  array ('label' => 'I rated max', 'type' => 'number'),

  array ('label' => 'Rdc max', 'type' => 'number')

);

while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_chart)){

  $temp = array();                                                          
  $temp[] = array('v' => (double) $r['L_value']);   

  $temp[] = array('v' => (double) $r['Irms']);

  $temp[] = array('v' => (double) $r['Rdc']);

  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
          var options = {
                  title: 'I/R-L chart',
                  hAxis: {title: 'L value [nH]', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}, logScale: true },
                  vAxes: { 0: {title: 'I value [A]', logScale: false}, 1: {title: 'Rdc value [Ohms]', logScale: false}},
                  series:{
                      0:{targetAxisIndex:0},
                      1:{targetAxisIndex:1}
                  },
                  pointSize:4,
                  lineWidth: 0

          }

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
```

I would like to add an onClick event in the rows of the table, so that when you click in one, in the graphic a vertical line is displayed (a vertical line in the correspondentant L value for that row).
Here the fiddle, with a table example (not all the values) and a graphic for that table http://jsfiddle.net/W2JWa/11/
Could someone help me?

Comment: do you mean click on the table(which table, you didn't create a table where someone may click?) or click on the chart?

Comment: could we see an example of these graphs / data in a fiddle to work with?

Comment: I need to add an onClick event in the <td> of the table, and call a javascript function that displays a vertical line in the correspondant L value. I didn't add any code for the table because I thought that it was irrelevant, but I can do it if it helps :)

Comment: Here the fiddle for the graph: http://jsfiddle.net/W2JWa/9/

Comment: ***I need to add an onClick event in the `<td>` of the table***...again...which table, there isn't a `<table>` somewhere, neither in your question nor in the fiddle

Comment: The table with some values and the graphic -http://jsfiddle.net/W2JWa/11/

Comment: @Dr.Molle I would like to ask you if you have an idea how to implement this... thanks!